# Prevent Docker not copying some files

Tags: docker

I use docker-compose (1.9.0) with docker (1.13.0). In my source file tree, I have a folder with all media of a web application. About 25Go in folder ./data/media.
How to prevent Docker from copying all these data while building image ? My /tmp folder becomes full because of these media and I can't rebuild.
Here is an extract of my docker-compose.yml, particulary my "data" service :

```
data:
  image: debian:jessie
  volumes:
#    - ./data/media:/srv/media
    - [...]
  command: "true"
```

As you can see, ./data/media is commented, so it should not copy these data.

Thanks for your help

Redfog